# Como leer varias lineas de un fichero binario

Tags: java

cree un fichero binario de instancias de medico, la cuestion es que no logro leer todas las lineas de este fichero. Existe la forma de leer todas las lineas de mi fichero binario?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi fichero binario.

```
public static List<Persona> leerLista() {
          List<Persona> lstPersona = null;
          try {
           ObjectInputStream in = 
            new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/formularioMedico.txt"));
           lstPersona = (List<Persona>) in.readObject();
           in.close();
           System.out.println("Archivo leído");
          } catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();} catch (ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
          return lstPersona;
         }
```

este es el metodo que cree para leer este archivo pero solo logro leer una linea.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta imagen se ve la linea que logro leer, pero quiero leerlas todas o incluso mas , porque quiero que el programa sea escalable, existe forma de hacerlo?

Comment: importa la manera en que lo escribes tambien, podrias poner informacion al respecto?

Comment: Todo indica que ese _binario_ es un serializado para una instancia de alguna clase, ¿verdad? Estaría bonito que mostraras cómo lo generaste para que recibas ayuda más oportuna. Deserializar una clase debe hacerse bien para no perder datos, y con cuidado para no exponerte a problemas de seguridad :)

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo que no toco java, pero creo recordar que lo que estas haciendo para leer, solo lee la primera línea, debes de crear un bucle que siga leyendo y mostrando mientras que la siguiente línea sea distinta de empty, puedes hacerlo con scanner.

algo tipo:

```
    while(!sc.nextLine().isEmpty()){
    lstPersona.add((List<Persona>) in.readObject());
}
```

como dije anteriormente, hace tiempo que no lo toco, pero debe ser algo por el estilo, comprobando la siguiente línea y en bucle ir añadiendo a la lista.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo.